# error.path.missing JSReader / Pinterest

Tags: pinterest

I'm using a pinterest API to get informations about pin. The JSON format of response is like this according to the api-explorer(https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/api-explorer/)

```
root:{} 1 item
  data:{} 3 items
    note:Pin 1
    image:{} 1 item
      original:{} 3 items
      url:https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/84/20/e4/8420e40cfd193e31371af8c981aaf23d.jpg
      width:206
      height:206
    id:100908847878850848
```

My case class is like this :

```
case class PagePin(description: String, picture: String)

object PagePinBuilder {
implicit val pagePinReads: Reads[PagePin] = (
(JsPath \ "root" \ "data" \ "note").read[String] and 
(JsPath \ "root" \ "data" \ "image" \ "original" \ "url").read[String]
)(PagePin.apply _)}
```

The error I get is : error.path.missing

I dont understand why ?? Can someone help me please ?

Comment: There is no `root` key. That represents the `root` object. Take that out of the path and you should be good.

Comment: I have the same error message even when I take out root or root and data.